# Ruby Array Elements Merging

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

just wondering if there're other alternatives to merging elements in an array from

> [  ["time","Oct-1-2016"],  ["message","test message"], 
>   ["host","localhost"] ]

to

> ["time=Oct-1-2016","message=test message","host=localhost"]

I've got it nailed down to`array.map {|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}` and just wondering if there are any other ways of achieving the above without using the map function? Thanks yo!

Comment: Still using `map` you can do: `arr.map {|s| s.join('=')}` as well.

Comment: Yea, I definitely overcooked the k,v portion - thanks @sagarpandya82

Comment: Of course: `[ ["time","Oct-1-2016"], ["message","test message"], ["host","localhost"] ].each_with_object([]) { |a,b| b << a.join('=') }`, but it is more cumbersome than simply `map`.

Comment: When you add a silly requirement like "without using the map function", you need to explain why, because the answer might be different. "I'm learning and we're not supposed to use it", "I am a Haskell survivor and those three letters standing side by side are aggravating me", "I've redefined `map` to always return `false` and I need help with gardenias holding my pacifier hostage" have wildly different responses. `map` is the best tool for the job; so without it you're working with a handicap.

Comment: If your endgame is to produce a query string, and since you've tagged this Rails, you might be interested in `to_param` which ActiveSupport mixes into `Hash`: `array.to_h.to_param => "host=localhost&message=test+message&time=Oct-1-2016"`. Otherwise, it's completely unclear why you would impose a restriction like "without the use of `map`" on your question.

Comment: @Amadan thanks for helping I guess. I did mention I achieved it and was wondering if there are other ways of achieving the same results without using map. If you can't understand the question why bother commenting?

Comment: @meagar was just merely exploring what other ways that one might attempt to replicate the map function but yes to_param is a good one. Thanks

Comment: @b1geyedeer: Because it will ultimately help you, to know that better questions produce better answers. For example, `to_param` uses `map`, so if the purpose is to write idiomatic and brief Rails code, it's great; but if it's to pass a class with an assignment that says "don't use `map`", it's a fail. With more context on why the limitation is there, you get more useful information back.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your array is `a`. Then try this solution:

```
[1] pry(main)> a = [ ["time","Oct-1-2016"], ["message","test message"], ["host","localhost"] ]
=> [["time", "Oct-1-2016"], ["message", "test message"], ["host", "localhost"]]

[2] pry(main)> a.map{|k, v| "#{k}=#{v}"}
=> ["time=Oct-1-2016", "message=test message", "host=localhost"]
```

Hm, I have no idea why `map` isn't works for you, but here is an example with `inject`:

```
[40] pry(main)> a.inject(Array.new){|acc, el| acc << el.join("="); acc}
=> ["time=Oct-1-2016", "message=test message", "host=localhost"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt @retgoat, I'm looking for alternatives other than using the map function to achieve the result in [2].

Comment: @b1geyedeer I added one more example. Hope that will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good alternative, just for the record map works but as I've mentioned I was wondering if there are other ways to achieve the same output other than map. Sorry if I get everyone riled up.

Comment: No worries mate :) I'm glad that was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using an infinite loop inside an `Enumerator` and by using the `cycle` method. Then use `enum.take arr.size` to get all your new elements in an array.

```
arr = [ ["time","Oct-1-2016"], ["message","test message"], ["host","localhost"] ]
ar  = arr.cycle

enum = Enumerator.new do |y|
  loop do
    y << ar.next.join('=')
  end
end

enum.take arr.size
#=> ["time=Oct-1-2016", "message=test message", "host=localhost"]
```